# Python, циклы, арифметическая прогрессия

Tags: python, циклы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот задачка, я не понимаю как можно вычислить сумму членов прогрессии не знаю конечный номер числа в этой прогрессии

Comment: Вам не нужен номер.  Вам нужно остановиться, когда член станет меньше заданного положительного е.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать решение, я вообще не понимаю что нужно сделать

Comment: Тогда берите учебник и изучайте тему. Иначе зачем вообще учиться? Или на биржу фрилансеров - за деньги все решат. А тут помогают тем, кто наткнулся на какую-то конкретную проблему и хочет разобраться. Т.е. выполните задание самостоятельно, пожалуйста, разместите вопрос о конкретном месте, где возникла проблема, желательно с её кратким анализом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заготовка решения:

- Перебирайте в цикле значения k, начиная с 1 и прибавляя к нему каждую итерацию по 1
- Вычисляйте a<sub>k</sub> по данной вам формуле
- Когда a<sub>k</sub> станет меньше или равно заданного вам числа e цикл нужно прекратить
- Суммируйте вместе получающиеся элементы a<sub>k</sub> пока цикл не прекратится
- Когда цикл закончится, напечатайте получившуюся сумму

Код вы должны написать самостоятельно, поскольку это учебное задание. Я вам разъяснил, что именно тут нужно делать.